# Use Redis to manage sessions in a spring project

Tags: java, spring, session, redis

I have a Spring-Mvc + Spring-Boot project where I want to manage the session with Redis.

I have this configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class SessionRepositoryConfig {

@Value("${redis.host}")
private String redisHostName;

@Value("${redis.port}")
private int redisPort;

@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHostName(redisHostName);
    factory.setPort(redisPort);
    factory.setUsePool(true);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
@Order(value = 0)
public FilterRegistrationBean sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration(SessionRepositoryFilter springSessionRepositoryFilter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new DelegatingFilterProxy(springSessionRepositoryFilter));
    filterRegistrationBean.setUrlPatterns(Arrays.asList("/*"));
    return filterRegistrationBean;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(24*60*60);
    return cacheManager;
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String,ExpiringSession> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, ExpiringSession> template = new RedisTemplate<String, ExpiringSession>();

    template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
    template.setHashValueSerializer(new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer());

    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return template;
}
}
```

When I try to login in the application, I have this error :

```
    2015-11-05 13:51:37.059 ERROR 7840 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Forwarding to error page from request [/login] due to exception [Could not read JSON: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: [B@580b1d7c; line: 1, column: 78]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: [B@580b1d7c; line: 1, column: 78]]
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: [B@580b1d7c; line: 1, column: 78]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1106) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:294) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:164) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:134) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:122) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:93) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:165) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:550) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:42) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3702) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2807) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:117) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Could not read JSON: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: [B@580b1d7c; line: 1, column: 78]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.DefaultSavedRequest]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: [B@580b1d7c; line: 1, column: 78]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:119) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.deserialize(GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.java:98) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:316) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:1.6.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.deserializeHashMap(AbstractOperations.java:277) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:1.6.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.entries(DefaultHashOperations.java:227) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:1.6.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.entries(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:101) ~[spring-data-redis-1.6.0.RELEASE.jar:1.6.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:233) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:220) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.getSession(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:141) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.getSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:253) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.loadContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:95) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:86) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:119) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65) ~[spring-session-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:69) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.M5.jar:1.3.0.M5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:116) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:60) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:91) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:109) [spring-boot-1.3.0.M5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [catalina.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_05]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.24]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_05]
```

I don't understand this error.

I know that it is linked to the GenericJacksonSerializer because the error disappear if I remove it. But I need to use it to have a readable redis database.

What can I change to fix this issue ? I tried to create a custom JsonSerializer with no success. Maybe I need to change another thing.

Comment: I met same issue, did you resolve it?

Comment: Unfortunatly I did not found a solution.
Currently I use a custom Serializer that I found here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751094.
It partially solves the problem but the session is not readable is redis database.

Comment: Looks like you just need to add a default constructor (without parameters) to your *DefaultSavedRequest* class