# Spring Boot Application with Hazelcast Backed Spring Session Serialization Exception on Active Directory Login Failure

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, hazelcast, spring-ldap, spring-session

We have a Spring Boot application using a Hazecast-backed Spring Session. The application authenicates with Active Directory using Spring Security.  If a user attempts to log in with invalid credentials, a serialization error is thrown:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.handleException(SerializationServiceImpl.java:380)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:235)
        at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:207)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapServiceContextImpl.toData(MapServiceContextImpl.java:338)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.toData(MapProxySupport.java:1160)
        at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.put(MapProxyImpl.java:96)
        at org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration$ExpiringSessionMap.put(HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration.java:112)
        at org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration$ExpiringSessionMap.put(HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration.java:102)
        at org.springframework.session.MapSessionRepository.save(MapSessionRepository.java:72)
        at org.springframework.session.MapSessionRepository.save(MapSessionRepository.java:36)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:194)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:128)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
        at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AbstractAjpProcessor.process(AbstractAjpProcessor.java:868)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This appears to be the identical to another issue ([Spring Boot with Session/Redis Serialization Error with Bad Active Directory Ldap Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751094/spring-boot-with-session-redis-serialization-error-with-bad-active-directory-lda)) with Redis, however there doesn't appear to be a similar mechanism to control serialization in the Hazelcast session mapping that there is for Redis in Spring Session.

We've come up with a workaround (below), but it seems less than ideal as `HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration` doesn't really seem to lend itself to extension, so it seems like there should be a cleaner way that we aren't seeing.

We are extending the `HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration` to get at the `ExpiringSessionMap` to remove the `LdapCtx` before serialization is attempted.  This doesn't seem ideal as the `HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration` doesn't really lend it self to extension, requiring duplication of code.

Is there a better solution that we're missing?

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomHazelcastHttpSessionMapConfiguration extends HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration{

    private String sessionMapName = "spring:session:sessions";
    private int maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 1800;

    @Bean
    public SessionRepository<ExpiringSession> sessionRepository(
            HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance, SessionEntryListener sessionListener) {
        super.sessionRepository(hazelcastInstance, sessionListener);

        MapSessionRepository sessionRepository = new MapSessionRepository(
                new CustomExpiringSessionMap(hazelcastInstance.getMap(this.sessionMapName)));
        sessionRepository
                .setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(this.maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds);

        return sessionRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSessionMapName(String sessionMapName) {
        this.sessionMapName = sessionMapName;
        super.setSessionMapName(sessionMapName);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds(int maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds) {
        this.maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds;
        super.setMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds);
    }

    static class CustomExpiringSessionMap implements Map<String, ExpiringSession> {
        private IMap<String, ExpiringSession> delegate;

        CustomExpiringSessionMap(IMap<String, ExpiringSession> delegate) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
        }

        public ExpiringSession put(String key, ExpiringSession value) {
            if (value == null) {
                return this.delegate.put(key, value);
            }
            for (String attrName : value.getAttributeNames()) {
                Object attrVal = value.getAttribute(attrName);
                // Don't serialize LdapCtx in a BadCredentialsException
                if (attrVal instanceof BadCredentialsException &&
                        ((BadCredentialsException) attrVal).getCause() != null &&
                        ((BadCredentialsException) attrVal).getCause() instanceof ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException &&
                        ((BadCredentialsException) attrVal).getCause().getCause() != null &&
                        ((BadCredentialsException) attrVal).getCause().getCause() instanceof javax.naming.AuthenticationException) {
                    ((javax.naming.AuthenticationException) ((BadCredentialsException) attrVal).getCause().getCause()).setResolvedObj(null);
                }
            }
            return this.delegate.put(key, value, value.getMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds(),
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }

    /*... copy and paste of the rest of ExpiringSessionMap */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure a [custom serialization](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#custom-serialization) for object(s) you're having issues with.

This way you would address your problem in Hazelcast configuration without extending/duplicating Spring Session's Hazelcast configuration.

Comment: Thanks, this made things quite a bit cleaner.  We implemented a custom serializer for ExpiringSession as that is the root object being serialized, and that ends up simplifying things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution would be `transient-attributes`.

If you have a web filter, you can pass it a list of properties to control the behaviour, and this one is a comma separated list of attribute names to exclude from serialization.

DM me if you need more info.