# Cannot serialize (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis, postman

I was developing a simple application to learn redis caching. Until I add redis as a caching mechanism on spring boot project the API's works fine. **REST** project you can say. Using Postman for calling different API. After adding redis I saw that `@CacheEvict` which is used for deleting data works fine. But when I call request like **GetMapping**, **PutMapping** which annotated with `@Cacheable`, `@CachePut` doesn't work. I don't understand what is the problem where `@CacheEvict` working perfectly `@Cacheable`, `@CachePut` doesn't.

Here is the **error** given by postman when I'm calling API's using following url:
**PUT:** `http://localhost:8080/bank/2/deposit`
**GET:** `http://localhost:8080/bank/holderName/Aysha`

```
{
    "dateTime": "2024-03-30T16:49:17.7557062",
    "message": "Cannot serialize",
    "error": "uri=/bank/2/deposit",
    "path": "Bad Request"
}
```

Let me explain in more detail how I configured redis:

**POM:**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.cache.type=redis
spring.cache.redis.time-to-live=60000
spring.cache.redis.host=localhost
spring.cache.redis.port=6379
```

**Account (Entity):**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String holderName;
    private double balance;
}
```

**Here I enabled caching:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class SimpleBankingApplication {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper mapper(){
        return new ModelMapper();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleBankingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller class:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("bank")
@AllArgsConstructor
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "account")
public class AccountController {
    private AccountService service;

    @PostMapping("createAccount")
    public ResponseEntity<AccountDTO> createAccount(@RequestBody @Valid AccountDTO dto){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.addAccount(dto), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    @GetMapping("holderName/{name}")
    @Cacheable(value = "account", key = "#name")
    public ResponseEntity<AccountDTO> getAccountByName(@PathVariable String name){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getAccount(name),HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
    @PutMapping("{id}/deposit")
    @CachePut(cacheNames = "account", key = "#id")
    public ResponseEntity<AccountDTO> deposit(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Map<String, Double> request){
        Double value = request.get("balance");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.deposit(id,value), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
    @PutMapping("{id}/withdraw")
    public ResponseEntity<AccountDTO> withdraw(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Map<String, Double> request){
        Double value = request.get("withdraw_balance");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.withdraw(id,value), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
    @GetMapping("allAccounts")
    public ResponseEntity<List<AccountDTO>> getAllAccount(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.getAllAccounts(),HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
    @DeleteMapping("deleteAccount/{id}")
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "account", key = "#id", beforeInvocation = true)
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteAccount(@PathVariable Long id){
        service.delete(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Account has been deleted!!!", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
}
```

**Project link:** [view the project](https://github.com/SakibvHossain/Simple-Banking-Application)

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace of the error. Probably you need to configure the JSON value serializer for Redis. The default serializer is binary as far as I know.

Comment: I try to use SLF4J and ExceptionHanlding to get more information about the error. unfortunately I have got nothing. I have only information that postman give me. Can you please help me find it out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implementing Serializable

```
public class AccountDTO implements Serializable {
//your fields, constructors, methods etc.
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57866376/17718213) is the reference.

Comment: It works fine if I don't use `ResponseEntity<>` else it throws the same error.

Comment: Where exactly the issue is coming from, service layer or controller layer? It doesn't look like a problem of api response.

Comment: The issue with `ResponseEntity<>` because When you wrap a class as Serializable, it allows instances of that class to be serialized into binary format. When returning an object of a Serializable class through a ResponseEntity in a Spring Boot application, it is typically converted into a textual format `(e.g., JSON, XML)` using message converters. 

When you return a Serializable object wrapped in a ResponseEntity then the problem occurs. if the message converters are not configured properly serialization issues may arise.

Comment: So message converter's improper configuration was the issue?

Comment: I fix the issue the way I said it works fine

Answer (score 0):

On your github code, you have changed the annotation @Controller to @RestController on the AccountController. It solved the problem? Because @RestController returns JSON. The next step is try to remove the mapper bean that you've created in SimpleBankingApplication class, because Spring manages it with Jackson JSON Mapper by default

Comment: After changing to @RestController still I'm having the same issue. I just used that model mapper to easily convert dto to entity & entity to dto.. Is data transfer object causing the error?

Comment: I call API without using DTO or you can say without using mapper. Still I got `Cannot serialize` on postman. Is there any way to fix the issue?

Comment: I saw some issue with `ResponseEntity<>` & `DTO`